# How do I get length of byte array returned by (.getBytes "string "UTF-8)?

Tags: clojure

There's something I'm not getting about Java interop.  I have a single character java.lang.String "x".  Java Strings have a getBytes method whose signature is `public byte[] getBytes(String charsetName) throws UnsupportedEncodingException`: 
 https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes(java.lang.String.

That method returns a byte[].  Java arrays have a property `.length`.  Why do I get an IllegalArgumentException in the REPL?

```
(.length (.getBytes "x" "UTF-8"))
IllegalArgumentException No matching field found: length for class [B  clojure.lang.Reflector.getInstanceField (Reflector.java:271)
```

How do I correctly get the length of the byte array returned by `(.getBytes "x" "UTF-8")` in clojure?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is the `alength` function in clojure.core to get the length of Java arrays

```
(alength (.getBytes "x" "UTF-8"))
;;=> 1
```

As far as I know, Java arrays are not really classes with a field called `length`, even though Java syntax `myarray.length` suggests otherwise. Getting the length of an array requires a special byte code instruction, not the typical field access. That's why the field access interop syntax in Clojure in this case results in an exception. And for the same reason a special purpose `alength` function is required.

Comment: Ah.  There it is.  "Java arrays are not really classes".  Thanks